# How can I loop through enum values for display in radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, enums, element

What is the proper way to loop through literals of an enum in TypeScript?

(I am currently using TypeScript 1.8.1.)

I've got the following enum:

```
export enum MotifIntervention {
    Intrusion,
    Identification,
    AbsenceTest,
    Autre
}

export class InterventionDetails implements OnInit
{
    constructor(private interService: InterventionService)
    {
        let i:number = 0;
        for (let motif in MotifIntervention) {
            console.log(motif);
        }
    }
```

The result displayed is a list

```
0
1
2
3
Intrusion,
Identification,
AbsenceTest,
Autre
```

I do want only four iterations in the loop as there are only four elements in the enum. I don't want to have 0 1 2 and 3 that seem to be index numbers of the enum.

Comment: checkout this [enum-for](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enum-for) package

Answer (score 680, accepted):

Two options:

```
for (let item in MotifIntervention) {
    if (isNaN(Number(item))) {
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

Or

```
Object.keys(MotifIntervention).filter(key => !isNaN(Number(MotifIntervention[key])));
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20MotifIntervention%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Intrusion%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Identification%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20AbsenceTest%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Autre%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(let%20item%20in%20MotifIntervention)%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(isNaN(Number(item)))%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log(item)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AObject.keys(MotifIntervention).filter(key%20%3D%3E%20!isNaN(Number(MotifIntervention%5Bkey%5D)))%3B))

---

#### Edit

String enums look different than regular ones, for example:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A = "a",
    B = "b",
    C = "c"
}
```

Compiles into:

```
var MyEnum;
(function (MyEnum) {
    MyEnum["A"] = "a";
    MyEnum["B"] = "b";
    MyEnum["C"] = "c";
})(MyEnum || (MyEnum = {}));
```

Which just gives you this object:

```
{
    A: "a",
    B: "b",
    C: "c"
}
```

You can get all the keys (`["A", "B", "C"]`) like this:

```
Object.keys(MyEnum);
```

And the values (`["a", "b", "c"]`):

```
Object.keys(MyEnum).map(key => MyEnum[key])
```

Or using [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
Object.values(MyEnum)
```

Comment: It doesn't work because 0 1 2 3 are strings.

Comment: That's why there's a check for `isNaN(Number(...))`. It works in the playground I shared

Comment: Yes it works, I must have missed something. I noticed it's the best solution that is not in the duplicated question.

Comment: Thanks for this approach.  For the `Object.keys` method, you'll want to use `Object.keys(MotifIntervention).filter(key => isNaN(Number(key)))`.

Comment: Shorter version that works with strict type checking:
```Object.keys(MotifIntervention).filter(key => isNaN(parseInt(key)))```
Doesn't work if some of the keys are integers, but I don't see why anyone would need it.

Comment: Since this answer didn't *quite* get me there, if it's helpful for anyone else using string enum to create an option list: `Object.keys(MyEnum).map(key => \`<option value="${key}">${MyEnum[key]}</option>\`);`

Comment: This doesn’t work if you're expecting to loop through values of the enum type. So `for (let item in MotifIntervention) { doThing(item) }` will fail if `typeof doThing` function is `(arg: MotifIntervention) => void`. That's because the `for..in` loop will treat `item` as type `string`, not type `MotifIntervention`.

Comment: @chharvey At runtime `MotifIntervention` is an object with two types of keys: numbers (but as strings) for the enum ordinals (i.e.: `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`...) and the strings for the enum value names (i.e.: `"Intrusion"`, `"Identification"`...). The `MotifIntervention` is `number` as far as the compiler is concerned, and so `isNaN(Number(item))` filters those out as the OP asked for the enum value names. If you want the ordinals (aka `MotifIntervention`) then just do `!isNaN(Number(item))`.

Comment: @NitzanTomer - that sounds like a good workaround at runtime, but i'm talking about compile time. When you attempt to call `doThing(item)` and `doThing` is of type `(arg: MotifIntervention) => void`, you'll get a compile time error **"Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MotifIntervention'."**

Comment: @chharvey Oh, well, in that case, you'll need to pass `Number(item)` and not `item`, so something like: `for (...) { const ordinal = Number(item);
    if (!isNaN(ordinal)) {
        doThing(ordinal);
    } }`

Comment: You can also cast it, if you need to pass the enum value as an enum type.. `for (let motif in MotifIntervention) { doThing(motif as MotifIntervention) }`

Comment: What @chharvey has brought up is an error I also encountered. This other question addresses it in a way that I was happy to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316326/typescript-ts7015-error-when-accessing-an-enum-using-a-string-type-parameter

Comment: I also include (typeof enumType[key] !== "function") in the filter to ignore methods I may have added to the enum type.

Comment: Why exactly does JavaScript include enum values in `Object.keys`?

Comment: this will not work for `enum X  {
   "012" = 1
}`