# How to access custom type value in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm new in typescript and I couldn't find the answer so I would like to ask how can I access to custom type value?

Let's say I have my custom type like this

```
type Notes = {
  5: number;
  10: number;
  20: number;
}
```

and I create instance like this

```
const availableNotes: Notes = {
  5: 10,
  10: 20,
  20: 40,
};
```

I tried to access the values of `availableNotes` like this

```
const noteTypes: string[] = Object.keys(availableNotes);

for(let i = 0; i < noteTypes.length; i++) {
  const value = availableNotes[noteTypes[i]] 
  ... // Some logic
}
```

And this is an error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ '5': number; '10': number; '20': number; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ '5': number; '10': number; '20': number; }'
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I iterate over a custom literal type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863488/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-custom-literal-type-in-typescript)

Comment: @AdrianKokot I don't think so because that answer is array instead of object. Appreciate your help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've spent some time trying different soultions and I've found a quite ugly one, but it works.

The whole magic is to cast type of the key to [`keyof Notes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html). At first, we need to cast `noteTypes[i]` to `unknown`, because TypeScript complies about casting `string` (`noteTypes[i]`) to `keyof Notes` directly.

Working example (tested on TypeScript v4.4.4 and v3.3.3):

```js
type Notes = {
  5: number;
  10: number;
  20: number;
}

const availableNotes: Notes = {
  5: 10,
  10: 20,
  20: 40,
};

const noteTypes = Object.keys(availableNotes);

for(let i = 0; i < noteTypes.length; i++) {
  const key = noteTypes[i] as unknown as (keyof Notes);
  const value = availableNotes[key];
  console.log(value);
}
```