# Get specific enum member from int in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, enzyme

I have a specific case here where I have a React button that has a class defined by an enum, the button selects the correct class through a switch statement, testing each member of the enum. This is hardcoded and this component works fine (code below).

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './SquareButton.css';

export interface Props {
    buttonType: ButtonType;
    style?: object;
}

const SquareButton = ({ buttonType, style }: Props) => {

    var className = "";
    switch (buttonType) {
        case ButtonType.Hamburger:
            className = "zmdi zmdi-menu zmdi-hc-2x";
            break;
        case ButtonType.Clock:
            className = "zmdi zmdi-time zmdi-hc-2x";
            break;
        case ButtonType.Wifi:
            className = "zmdi zmdi-network-wifi zmdi-hc-2x";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return (
        <div className="squareButton" style={style} >
            <i className={className} />
        </div>
    )
}

export enum ButtonType {
    Wifi,
    Hamburger,
    Clock
}

export default SquareButton;
```

The issue I'm having is in testing this component, as this list of `enum ButtonType` is likely to grow I want to be able to loop through each button type without having to write individual tests or adding new ones each time there's a new button. Example test below.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(ButtonType).length / 2; i++) {
    test(ButtonType[i] + 'square button icon class must contain zmdi', () => {
        const button = Enzyme.shallow(<SquareButton buttonType={i as ButtonType} />)
        expect(button.find('div').find('i').hasClass("zmdi")).toEqual(true);
    });
}
```

This successfully loops though each member in the enum but I can't figure out how to get the specific enum instance in the loop to pass to the component. Passing `i as ButtonType` still only passes an int value and the default in the switch is hit. I've tried lots of variations/string conversions etc but nothing I've tried works (the tests work if I hardcode an (e.g.) `ButtonType.Wifi` value).

How can I get a specific enum member from an integer value?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372804/typescript-how-to-loop-through-enum-values-for-display-in-radio-buttons help?

Comment: Unfortunately not, "item" in that case just returns a string, the same as if I tried ButtonType[i] on each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `i` integer is already desired value, `ButtonType.Hamburger === 0`, etc.

The problem with iterating through enum is that enum values aren't necessarily numbers, and it's unnecessary that half of enum keys are numeric indexes.

```
enum A {
        B,
        C,
        D = 'D'
}
```

results in these keys:

```
["0", "1", "B", "C", "D"]
```

A fail-safe way would be:

```
for (const enumKey of Object.keys(ButtonType).filter(key => isNaN(+key))) {
  const enumVal = ButtonType[enumKey] as ButtonType;

  test(`ButtonType.${enumKey} square button icon class must contain zmdi`, () => {
    const button = Enzyme.shallow(<SquareButton buttonType={enumVal} />)
    ...
  })
}
```

Since it's preferable to also test classes that are specific to `ButtonType` like `zmdi-menu`, there should also be respective tests, so generic tests with iteration may be unneeded.