# Typescript enum values as array

Tags: arrays, typescript, enums

Is it possible to get the values of an enum in TypeScript as an array?

Like this:

```js
enum MyEnum {
    FOO = 'foo',
    BAR = 'bar'
}
```

becomes

```js
['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use:

```
Object.values(MyEnum)
```

because enum is an JS object after compilation:

```
var MyEnum;
(function (MyEnum) {
    MyEnum["FOO"] = "foo";
    MyEnum["BAR"] = "bar";
})(MyEnum || (MyEnum = {}));
```

Comment: This answer is not correct for number enums

Answer (score 12):

For a fully typed code, you may want to infer the list of values as a type with some help of the [template literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) operator:

```js
enum MyEnum {
    FOO = 'foo',
    BAR = 'bar'
}

type MyEnumValue = `${MyEnum}`
// => type MyEnumValue = "foo" | "bar"

const values: MyEnumValue[] = Object.values(MyEnum)
// => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Reference article: [Get the values of an enum dynamically](https://dev.to/prod/mastering-enums-in-typescript-1c1j#enum-get-values)
*(disclaimer: author here)*

Comment: This answer is not correct for number enums

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to do it for a `string` enum is to use `Object.values`

```
enum MyEnum {
    FOO = 'foo',
    BAR = 'bar'
}
console.log(Object.values(MyEnum));
```

Comment: this answer is in more detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372804/how-can-i-loop-through-enum-values-for-display-in-radio-buttons

Answer (score 5):

Edit:

Imho @Fyodor's solution is cleaner because it covers string enums:

```
const enumAsArray = Object.values(MyEnum).filter(value => typeof value === 'string')
```

Comment: Or `const enumAsArray = Object.values(MyEnum).filter(value => typeof value === 'string')` 

(replace 'string' with necessary type)

To remove indexes I mean

Comment: Also a nice approach :)

Comment: This looks weird.. Why cut half of values? What if we have odd length? Splice is definitely not needed.

Answer (score 4):

This function should work with numeric enums as well and it type-checks:

```js
type EnumObject = {[key: string]: number | string};
type EnumObjectEnum<E extends EnumObject> = E extends {[key: string]: infer ET | string} ? ET : never;

function getEnumValues<E extends EnumObject>(enumObject: E): EnumObjectEnum<E>[] {
  return Object.keys(enumObject)
    .filter(key => Number.isNaN(Number(key)))
    .map(key => enumObject[key] as EnumObjectEnum<E>);
}
```

For example:

```js
enum NumEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}
// The type is inferred as NumEnum[]
let numEnumValues = getEnumValues(NumEnum);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgVwLYHkBGArCBjYUC8UA3gNoDWEIAXFAM7ABOAlnAOYC6NiSaEDUAHzqMWrAL4BuAFChIsbuiy54yADwwoEAB7AIcACa15yRTmAA+ArE069h4uUo16zNpygsAZn1gAVQcKu4lAA-H5QXBAAbnzSUp4IcLhMAPZwUKwQwCpIAGoAhgA2CBC06ja6BkY5prjmABR6JphmNDAAlG0KLcrc6uYk7MRSUFAMWQgM6bXAAHQUILSN3UrA7SOjULOeTIW6DPULBJYAcsi8DLNMtCf5J-VnPHyHlO1vG6OzSPlgLyDHmhWZkcICG+WqQN6ahg5na0jEUikTSQUEeOWGmygAEEADQfKAAITxmIAwniEQB6ClQXwAC2gsmg1w8cG8DHG+ig4NRyBygykhSyUG4OQKxVKVky2W4YpKSzR3DhUmwaVoKUFs0KKVY9RFMqKcqVSO4UAAyiI2OiiPisVYAET5O3EzYE+1oJ34kn27AeynUukM8BMoxePgcrlGc1BPnsAVClyiUUGiWEKVJ8VLKOJxXSFVwNUarU6hOW-UZpVAA)

I've posted more details here: [How to get an array of enum values in TypeScript](https://blog.oyam.dev/typescript-enum-values/)

Comment: This will not work for
`
enum X  {
   "012" = 1
}
`