# Converting TypeScript's enum with string values to an array

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-typings

I have the following enum object in TypeScript:

```
enum ClassesTypes {
  READY = 'ready',
  DELETED = 'deleted',
}
```

How can I get from it the following array? `['ready', 'deleted']`?

- Tried to use the following code:

```
const arr = Object.keys(ClassesTypes).map(key => ClassesTypes[key]);
```

But get the following error:

> TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.>

- When I tried to change it to the following according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316326/typescript-ts7015-error-when-accessing-an-enum-using-a-string-type-parameter)

```
const arr = Object.keys(ClassesTypes).map((key: keyof typeof ClassesTypes) => ClassesTypes[key]);
```

I get the following error:

> TS2345: Argument of type '(key: "READY" | "DELETED") => ClassesTypes' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => ClassesTypes'.
>     Types of parameters 'key' and 'value' are incompatible.
>       Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"READY" | "DELETED"'

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036446/typescript-enum-values-as-array) is a possible solution.

Comment: Just `Object.values(ClassesTypes)`