# How to show enum text values in Dropdown?

Tags: angular, angular10, angular11

This is my enum values

```
export enum TaskCategory {
    Task = 0,
    Bug = 1,
}
```

html

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Task Category <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                    <select class="select form-control" 
                        [class.invalid]="addTaskForm.get('taskcategory').invalid && addTaskForm.get('taskcategory').touched"
                        formControlName="taskcategory">
                        <option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">Select Task Category</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let state of states | keyvalue"  >{{state['value']}}</option>
                      

                    </select>
                    <div
                        *ngIf="addTaskForm.get('taskcategory').invalid && addTaskForm.get('taskcategory').touched">
                        <small
                            *ngIf="addTaskForm.get('taskcategory').invalid && addTaskForm.get('taskcategory').touched"
                            class="text-danger"> *Task Category is required</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image: This the console Output.. Check this]

I want only show the Enum text value ?

And how to get that selected option in backend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the enum in a template you can do:

```
taskCategories: typeof TaskCategory = TaskCategory;
```

For number enums you need to filter the numeric values out.

```
categoryKeys: string[] = Object.keys(this.taskCategories).filter(
  key => !isNaN(Number(this.taskCategories[key]))
);
```

For more details check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372804/how-can-i-loop-through-enum-values-for-display-in-radio-buttons)

To send the selected option to the backend you need to make use of the HttpClient. The usual way is to import it in a service and do something similar to:

```
sendData(payload) {
  return this.http.post(this.url, payload);
}
```

Then in your component:

```
// Todo: bind to a button
sendData() {
  this.appService.sendData(this.selectedCategory).subscribe(res => {
    // handle response
  });
}
```

I recommend reading up on it [here](https://angular.io/guide/http)

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wbg88v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)