# Typescript String Enums access

Tags: typescript, enums, enumeration

first of all I think I am missing something about Typescript and Enums although I have done all my studies.

So here we go:

I have lets say the following Enum:

```
export enum LapTypes {
  'Start' = 'Start',
  'Stop' = 'Start',
  'Manual' = 'Manual',
  'manual' = 'Manual',
  'Autolap' = 'Auto lap',
  'AutoLap' = 'Auto lap',
  'autolap' = 'Auto lap',
  'Distance' = 'Distance',
  'distance' = 'Distance',
  'Location' = 'Location',
  'location' = 'Location',
  'Time' = 'Time',
  'time' = 'Time',
  'HeartRate' = 'Heart Rate',
  'position_start' = 'Position start',
  'position_lap' = 'Position lap',
  'position_waypoint' = 'Position waypoint',
  'position_marked' = 'Position marked',
  'session_end' = 'Session end',
  'fitness_equipment' = 'Fitness equipment',
}
```

And at a Class of mine I use it like:

```
export class Lap  {

  public type: LapTypes;

  constructor(type: LapTypes) {
    this.type = type;
  }

}
```

When I create a new lap as so:

`const lap = new Lap(LapTypes.AutoLap);`

All is fine.

Then again if I do this:

`const lapType = 'AutoLap';`

this `new Lap(LapTypes[lapType])` works just fine

However, since I want a dynamic Laptype I am trying to do the following:

`const lapType: string = someJSON['Type'];`

but when I try to create a new Lap

`new Lap(LapTypes[lapType])`

I get:

> element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

I am sure I am missing something fundamendal here and need to restudy my typescipt.

I would like some help on what I am doing wrong and where to look to broaden my knowledge.

Comment: Is the laptype from the JSON what you expect it to be or is it some other value? And also the way you use the enum, to me it seems that a map would be more appropriate.

Comment: @MarkoTaht its a sting inside the JSON and I am getting this in compile type. In sort it wont let me compile. I am using the latest TS. 
I could make it a map or a const with index but I would like to narrow down the cases with an Enum as of API first approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316326/typescript-ts7015-error-when-accessing-an-enum-using-a-string-type-parameter Here someone had the same issue. What you have to do is LapTypes[<any>lapType].

Comment: Does something like `const lapType = <keyof typeof LapTypes>someJSON['Type']` work?

Comment: @MarkoTaht that does not work

Comment: @estus I ll try this in a bit

Comment: @estus That worked! Thanks man. Any blue why?

Comment: @estus I ll be glad to accept your comment as an aswer if there is a bit of explanation as well. The other answer by fateme does not work or sound logical.

Comment: You're welcome, hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since enum member names are specific strings and not just random strings, `string` isn't a proper type for enum key.

If `someJSON.Type` is `any`, it can be:

```
const lapType: keyof typeof LapTypes = someJSON['Type'];
new Lap(LapTypes[lapType]);
```

If `someJSON.Type` has been already typed as `string`, it can be:

```
const lapType = <keyof typeof LapTypes>someJSON['Type'];
new Lap(LapTypes[lapType]);
```

Considering that `someJSON` is untyped or loosely typed, it should be properly typed as early as possible. `keyof typeof LapTypes` type should preferably be specified for `Type` property at `someJSON` variable definition.

Comment: Loud and clear and what I was starting to suspect but did not really know! Thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

simply use: `new Lap(LapTypes[lapType as LapTypes])`