# Dynamic Enum keys in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have defined

```
enum Sort {
  nameAsc = 'nameAsc',
  nameDesc = 'nameDesc'
}
```

Can I do something like this?

```
const key = 'name' + 'Desc';
Sort[key]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamically access enum in typescript by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50417254/dynamically-access-enum-in-typescript-by-key)

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

This:

```
// index.ts
enum Sort {
    nameAsc = 'nameAscValue',
    nameDesc = 'nameDescValue'
}
const key = 'name'+'Desc';
console.log(Sort[key]);
```

Compiles to (using `tsc index.ts`):

```
// index.js
var Sort;
(function (Sort) {
    Sort["nameAsc"] = "nameAscValue";
    Sort["nameDesc"] = "nameDescValue";
})(Sort || (Sort = {}));
var key = 'name' + 'Desc';
console.log(Sort[key]);
```

Which outputs (using `node index.js`):

```
nameDescValue
```

Comment: It only compiles if `noImplictAny` is not turned on and isn't type-safe. WIth no implicit any you need an extra assertion `Sort[key as keyof typeof Sort]`