# Get TypeScript enum numeric value by member name

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I'm converting one of my JavaScript apps to TypeScript and I've got a problem: I've got a numeric enum, `AnswerKeys` and a `key`, `"C"`. I'd like to get the member's value, `"2"`, so [I tried using `AnswerKeys[key]`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiDOB3YAnA0sAnvKBvAsAFBRQDkMpUAvFAAwA0RJpAQqY8WQMLtEC%20RADbAALlADWWat1JDRUAIYJkKaXCSoM2ANqTMAXSIBjAPYITwgHSCTAcwAUSjSgCUQA).

```
enum AnswerKeys {
  'A' = 0,
  'B',
  'C',
}
let key = 'C'
let answer = AnswerKeys[key]
// it should log 2
console.log(answer)
```

It would work but I receive the following TypeScript error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not
> of type 'number'.

It seems it has a problem with `key` not being a number. Other answers suggested adding `as any` assertion or just adding `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true` to the config file, and while these do suppress the error, it's not what I want.

The following works but accepts any `key` and I only want to accept strings:

```
let answer = AnswerKeys[key as any]
```

I also tried `keyOf AnswerKeys` but it [results in an extra error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiDOB3YAnA0sAnvKBvAsAFBRQDkMpUAvFAAwA0RJpAQqY8WQMLtEC%20RADbAALlADWWAFwSsAewBmsBMnRYcNUjyGioAQxWpqypKgzYA2pMwBdIgGM5COcIB0guQHMAFAdMoASiA):

```
enum AnswerKeys {
  'A' = 0,
  'B',
  'C',
}
let key: keyof AnswerKeys = 'C'
let answer = AnswerKeys[key]
console.log(answer)
```

> Type '"C"' is not assignable to type '"toString" | "toFixed" |
> "toExponential" | "toPrecision" | "valueOf" | "toLocaleString"'.(2322)

Is there any way to annotate it correctly?

Comment: Do you need `key` to change?  If not, you can write `const key = "C"` [and it works](https://tsplay.dev/W4P3XW).  If you're looking for an annotation, you could write `keyof typeof AnswerKeys` and not `keyof AnswerKeys` (which is [different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218)), [and that works too](https://tsplay.dev/Na2gEm).  Which one are you looking for?  I'm happy to write up either version as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, `const key` does work, but `key` is actually a parameter, it's not in the question because I tried to simplify it. It started as `function func(key: string) {...}` and I received the error mentioned above. It seems `function func(key: keyof typeof AnswerKeys) {` is what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: All right I guess [there's already an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73179933/get-typescript-enum-numeric-value-by-member-name/73180003#73180003) that says that.

Comment: @jcalz Any idea why (alternatively) [`typeof AnswerKeys[AnswerKeys]`](https://tsplay.dev/Wz53km) doesn't work? Or, in other words, why does TS implement [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) for numeric enums but hide the related type information?

Comment: It's an open issue, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38806

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamically access enum in typescript by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50417254/dynamically-access-enum-in-typescript-by-key)

Comment: @chitinlink I don't think it's a duplicate. Which one of those do you think answers my question the same way or better than the accepted answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a union of all of the enum values, you can use `keyof typeof Enum`. This is because `keyof Enum` gives you the keys of the *object* `Enum` (as AnswerKeys is technically just an object/value), whereas you want the keys of the *type* `Enum`.

Using your example, the following runs with no errors:

```js
enum AnswerKeys {
  'A' = 0,
  'B',
  'C',
}
let key: keyof typeof AnswerKeys = 'C'
let answer = AnswerKeys[key]
console.log(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the following methods:

**1. Modify `tsconfig.json`**
Add/uncomment `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true` in `tsconfig.json`.
In newer versions of Typescript, it is called `noImplicitAny`.
Documentation can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors).

**2. `key as keyof typeof AnswerKeys`**

```
let key = 'C'
let answer = AnswerKeys[key as keyof typeof AnswerKeys]
```

**3. Disable linting for the line using `@ts-ignore`**

```
let key = 'C'
// @ts-ignore
let answer = AnswerKeys[key]
```

**4. Set `key` to type `any`**

```
let key: any = 'C'
let answer = AnswerKeys[key]
```

Sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40997325/ & https://stackoverflow.com/a/66117678/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I definitely don't want to use #1, #3, and #4 as I mentioned in my question. My problem with #2 is that it still [accepts anything](https://tsplay.dev/NDy4Vm) because `as keyof typeof AnswerKeys` is just a way to tell the compiler not to give you an error message.