# Access to property by enum value

Tags: typescript, angular5

I'm trying to get access to property by string variable in TypeScript. When I write `d["account_type"]` everything is ok, but when I use one of enums `Dictionary` and write `d[Dictionary.AccountType]`, I see the error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Dictionaries' has no index signature.

```
this.dictionaries.toPromise().then(d => { return d["account_type"] });

export enum Dictionary {
    AccountType = "account_type",
    AddressType = "address_type",
    CardBrand = "card_brand",
    ContactType = "contact_type",
    Country = "country",
    DevicePayDay = "device_pay_type",
    LogType = "log_type",
    PaymentProvider = "payment_provider",
    PaymentType = "payment_type",
    Permission = "permission",
    PointProperty = "point_property",
    PointService = "point_service",
    PromoSchemaOn = "promo_schema_on",
    PromoSchemaOff = "promo_schema_off",
    ReportType = "report_type",
}
```

Is there any way to get access to object properties by enum string value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript TS7015 error when accessing an enum using a string type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316326/typescript-ts7015-error-when-accessing-an-enum-using-a-string-type-parameter)

Comment: What is the type of `Dictionaries`?  It likely needs to be changed to something like `Record<Dictionary, unknown>` but you didn't include it here so I don't know how to advise.  It helps to provide a [mcve] so others can reproduce the issue and test and suggest a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
this.dictionaries.toPromise().then((d: any) => { return d[Dictionary.AccountType] });
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-value-by-enum

Comment: This is not a solution, it's a workaround. You're basically making `d` an explicit `any` instead of an implicit `any`. The accepted answer of the duplicate shows how to do this appropriately.

Comment: It works, why it is not proper way? I'm fighting with angular for some time but I don't understund core mechanisms I think:/

Comment: In my opinion it is not workaround, you can use anonymous type for this case and it is simple and common