# Typescript: Cast a string to a number enum?

Tags: typescript, enums, casting

I have an enum that needs to remain as a number enum - so i can't change it to a string.

I would like to cast a string to the correct enum without doing a long switch :-)

for example, here is my enum

```
export enum LogLevel {
  TRACE = 0,
  DEBUG = 1,
  INFO = 2,
  LOG = 3,
  WARN = 4,
  ERROR = 5,
  FATAL = 6,
  OFF = 7
}
```

I get a string passed to me, lets say the string is "WARN" that I need to have a variable that is equal to

```
LogLevel.WARN
```

Casting between strings and enum strings is easy but no so easy when I need to keep the enum as a numbered enum.

Any ideas the best way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

** EDIT **

Actaully its a compiler error showing the following

TypeScript TS7015 error when accessing an enum using a string type parameter

There is a fix here

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17800

```
    let s: string = "WARN"
    console.log(LogLevel[s as keyof typeof LogLevel]) // 4
```

Comment: Did you try using the string as an index? Like this `LogLevel[str]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are [available as a runtime construct](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-runtime), you can index into the enum using a string:

```
let s: string = "WARN";
console.log(LogLevel[s]); // 4
```

[On the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20LogLevel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20TRACE%20%3D%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20DEBUG%20%3D%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20INFO%20%3D%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20LOG%20%3D%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20WARN%20%3D%204%2C%0D%0A%20%20ERROR%20%3D%205%2C%0D%0A%20%20FATAL%20%3D%206%2C%0D%0A%20%20OFF%20%3D%207%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20s%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22WARN%22%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(LogLevel%5Bs%5D)%3B).

Comment: Thanks, yes it was a TS7015 error, but after you confirming it was the correct way - it lead me to look why. So accepting your answer thanks!

I updated my answer

Comment: @IanGregson - Gotcha. Are [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316326/typescript-ts7015-error-when-accessing-an-enum-using-a-string-type-parameter) relevant? I wonder if we should mark this a duplicate of that.