# an create type using key in enum has implicitly 'any' problem [angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Why does the key of [type] need a type? It's really weird to say that, but I have a problem.

data example:

```
export enum ENUM_Bike {
 suzuki   = 'suzuki',
 yamaha   = 'yamaha',
 kawasaki = 'kawasaki'
}

export type TBike_StringMapping = { [key in ENUM_Bike]: string };

export const CONST_BikeIconName: Readonly<TBike_StringMapping> = {
 suzuki   : 'icon_a',
 yamaha   : 'icon_b',
 kawasaki : 'icon_c',
}

export const CONST_BikeIconColor: Readonly<TBike_StringMapping> = {
 suzuki   : '#111',
 yamaha   : '#222',
 kawasaki : '#333',
}
```

using

```
<mat-icon
 *ngFor="let item of CONST_BikeIconName | keyvalue: orderByJson"
 [ngStyle]="{'background-color': CONST_BikeIconColor[item.key] }">
    {{ item.value }}
</mat-icon>
```

I have been using it like this, but now it appears

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Readonly<TBike_StringMapping>'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Readonly<TBike_StringMapping>'.ts(7053)

I found a discussion, but it can't solve my problem. I need type not interface. Can anyone help me? thanks for the help.

[TypeScript TS7015 error when accessing an enum using a string type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316326/typescript-ts7015-error-when-accessing-an-enum-using-a-string-type-parameter)

Edit to Rachid O: there has same example here, and same error

[error example on typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwKIDkCqBZAfQCEBLAa2DgG8AoOAZ2QC9kyS4OBeOAckZbY8ANHQCeAQ1TiAFuI5xuPCVNnC6ZcQHdx9cWwW8N23YJoBfGjVCRYcGKLCUAKqQoEAyjCglEAczziYGA%20vgZUcADaFKJwPpi4hK7AALoAXAxeIXBmANyW1tDwAMYQiPTwAMIA8ljuTsTkwACSJYhYksDpAErA4gAmpQA2ogA8Lo0emX4BQSEAfGF0-KzsHOk8JK0E4mpwyjJya7ybpQQARrtGOnrs6yeIBEVqFlbghXCt5XDVtfVJLaUKhBBtBur0BohhmMkpNvNNAsE-AtuLQGMwVvJ1gBiACMeN2%201kmN4WIATOTLlprvpsQBmenPSwAM2gcAAFJ94NFYohvjU6g0KAC2h0AJTUOjyEhM9nRcWo%20SchCDYCoJDwbg-AX-VpAkFQKLAUTJPLybLmIA)

Comment: are you sure of the problem ? I don't see any errors. What version of Angular Material are you using ?

Comment: it's really problem, please see my edited supplementary note, there has online typescript example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one quick solution for this problem would be to exactly do what the compiler suggests and add an intermediate type that has an index signature like so :

```
export interface TBike_StringMappingExtended extends TBike_StringMapping {
    [key: string]:string
}
```

this will give :

```
export enum ENUM_Bike {
 suzuki   = 'suzuki',
 yamaha   = 'yamaha',
 kawasaki = 'kawasaki'
}

export type TBike_StringMapping = Record<ENUM_Bike, string>;

export interface TBike_StringMappingExtended extends TBike_StringMapping {
    [key: string]:string
}

export const CONST_BikeIconName: TBike_StringMappingExtended = {
 suzuki   : 'icon_a',
 yamaha   : 'icon_b',
 kawasaki : 'icon_c',
}

export const CONST_BikeIconColor: TBike_StringMappingExtended = {
 suzuki   : '#111',
 yamaha   : '#222',
 kawasaki : '#333',
}

for (let key in CONST_BikeIconName) {
    if (key) {
    const element = CONST_BikeIconColor[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, this gave me a new understanding of the usage of types and interfaces. In addition, I found that if I use value as an index in the loop of html, the error will not appear.

Comment: If use your solution, no matter whether use key or value as an index in the html loop, no error will occur.